# CSS Box border bottom stick to top?

Tags: html, css

I am writing my own css, but the strange thing is that the my `.content` `border-top` and `border-bottom` are sticking together.[image]

Here is my code for css:

```css
body{
    width: 100%; 
    margin: auto;
    }    
header{
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px;
    min-width: 1200px;
    min-height: 70px; 
    }
p{
    font-family: courier;
    font-size: 130%;
    margin: 10%;
    }
.content{
    margin-top: 100px;
    min-width: 1200px;
    border-top: 3px solid orange;
    border-bottom: 30px solid rgb(239, 98, 98);
}
.content .col-left{
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    }    
.content .col-mid{
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    }
.content .col-right{
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    }
.footer{
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        
        <title>IEEI</title>
        
        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/customized.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
        </header>  
        
        
        <div class="content">
            <div class="col-left"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x150" style="width:100%"></div>
            <div class="col-mid">
                <p>
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV.
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-right"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x150" style="width:100%"></div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="content">
            <p>test footer</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="footer">
            <p>test footer</p>
        </div>  
        <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am wondering how to move the red border bottom to the right position.
I have tried to put a new content box in the HTML, the position seems to be OK but messes up the output. I am new to the CSS, please help me out.

Comment: Set the `position` of `.content` to `relative` and `float` to `left`. This should work.

Comment: you're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.content` element only contains floated elements, which "don't count" concerning the borders and size of their container element. Add `overflow: auto;` to `.content` to make `.content` wrap its floating contents:

```css
body{
    width: 100%; 
    margin: auto;
    }    
header{
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px;
    min-width: 1200px;
    min-height: 70px; 
    }
p{
    font-family: courier;
    font-size: 130%;
    margin: 10%;
    }
.content{
    margin-top: 100px;
    min-width: 1200px;
    border-top: 3px solid orange;
    border-bottom: 30px solid rgb(239, 98, 98);
    overflow: auto;
}
.content .col-left{
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    }    
.content .col-mid{
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    }
.content .col-right{
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    }
.footer{
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        
        <title>IEEI</title>
        
        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/customized.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
        </header>  
        
        
        <div class="content">
            <div class="col-left"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x150" style="width:100%"></div>
            <div class="col-mid">
                <p>
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV.
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                    Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-right"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x150" style="width:100%"></div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="content">
            <p>test footer</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="footer">
            <p>test footer</p>
        </div>  
        <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also would be a good idea to provide some height to the element of .content ID.